# How can we render child component whenever parent component is updated?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

The child component constructs a field based on a set of properties of an object that is passed to child as a parameter. In the below example, how can the child component render dynamically when any of the address fields change in the parent ? Thanks for any suggestions!

The parent component uses a child component as below and passes a parameter `parentObj`.

Parent Component:

```
<Child ChildObj="@parentObj" />
```

Child component:

```
<div class="col-8 flex-wrap">
    @Address
</div>

@code {

[Parameter]
public Person ChildObj { get; set; }

public string Address { get; set; }


 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { 
            if (ChildObj != null)
            {
                Address = ChildObj.Address1 + " " + ChildObj.Address2 + " " + ChildObj.City + " " + ChildObj.State + " " + ChildObj.Zip
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: After you set the address call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `OnInitializedAsync` is called only in the first time that the parameters are set in the component, you need to use [OnParametersSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-parameters-are-set) that will be called when:

> OnParametersSetAsync or OnParametersSet are called:
>
> - After the component is initialized in OnInitializedAsync or OnInitialized.
> - When the parent component re-renders and supplies:
>     Only known primitive immutable types of which at least one parameter has changed.
>     Any complex-typed parameters. The framework can't know whether the values of a complex-typed parameter have mutated internally, so it treats the parameter set as changed.

```
<div class="col-8 flex-wrap">
    @Address
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Person ChildObj { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    // using OnParametersSet
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (ChildObj != null)
        {
            Address = ChildObj.Address1 + " " + ChildObj.Address2 + " " + ChildObj.City + " " + ChildObj.State + " " + ChildObj.Zip
        }
    }
}
```